# Meaning of the word "sprizzle"

Tags: slang, informal-language

Recently I discovered a song where the singer mentions the word sprizzle. I looked it up on UrbanDictionary, but the definitions there don't seem to fit. Translated, he says in the song

"we chill with a sprizzle "

Comment: this is a type of slang from early 90s rap (which may still be around)... it's not heard much in spontaneous dialogue and is used playfully)... wherein a word-ending is replaced with -izzle (like fo' shizzle = for sure.) I'm not answering your question because I don't know in this particular case. It should be some word starting with Spr. Maybe the beverage Sprite?

Comment: sprizzle means some fluid sprayed example : The water that sprays off of other vehicles when driving in the rain.

Comment: thanks for your explanation hunter. 90's rap inspired slang  would definitely be possible. Sprite could also be, but I'll guess it should probably just sound cool

Comment: Hey @hunter, that's pretty much the answer, I think. You should submit it as one. It might help if we knew which song it was. Lacking that, I still feel pretty confident it's Sprite.

Comment: A *spritzer* is a type of drink.  dictionary.com:  noun. a tall drink made with chilled wine and soda.

Answer (score 1):

**Sprizzle is probably the soft drink [Sprite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28soft_drink%29)**

I can't be certain without knowing which song you're referring to, but that's my best guess. This would be an instance of the [-izzle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-izzle) phenomenon, where you replace a word with it's first sound followed by the suffix -izzle. It was popularized by rappers, particularly Snoop Dogg, in the '90s.